# How to do difference between 2 times objects in lua?

Tags: lua

I am trying to write some code in Lua.
the code is supposed to do this thing: analyze .log file that contains a lot of lines,
each line has 3 columns: the first column is time-string format 00:00:00,
the second one is [id] and the third is an action- string like log-in, log-out and so on.
what I need to do is to print for each worker(id) the average hours per day according to his log-ins and log-outs actions.
here is my solution:

```
function averageHoursPerWorker()
fh,err = io.open("log2.log")
if err ~= nil then
        print (err)
        return
        end
numOfDaysPerWorkerArray = {}
amountOfHoursPerWorkerArray = {}
logInsPerWorker = {}
logOutsPerWorker = {}
hour = ''
worker = ''
action = ''

while true do
        stuff = fh.read(fh)
        if stuff == nil then break end
        lynetab = {}
        for i in string.gmatch(stuff,"(%S+)") do
                lynetab[#lynetab+1] = i
                -- print (i)
                end
        --here, lynatab contains one line. this is the logic
        hour = lynetab[1]
        action = lynetab[3]
        worker = lynetab[2]
        if action == 'log-in' then --save the certain worker log-in hour
            logInsPerWorker[worker] = hour
        end
        if action == 'log-out' then
            logOutsPerWorker[worker] = hour --save the certain worker log-out hour
            if not (logInsPerWorker[worker] == 0) then --this worker already logged in
                if amountOfHoursPerWorkerArray[worker] == nil then --initialize worker's hours%days counter
                    amountOfHoursPerWorkerArray[worker] = 0
                    numOfDaysPerWorkerArray[worker] = 0
                end
                -- print(math.floor(os.difftime(makeTimeStamp(logOutsPerWorker[worker]),makeTimeStamp(logInsPerWorker[worker]))))

                --add this hours to worker's hours counter and add one day to days counter of this worker
                --i know that the results are wrong- this is because the - operator did not do his job...
                --i had no more time to figure it out but i do believe it's something pretty simple to solve.
                -- print(GetTimeDifference(logOutsPerWorker[worker],logInsPerWorker[worker]))
                amountOfHoursPerWorkerArray[worker] = amountOfHoursPerWorkerArray[worker] + makeTimeStamp(logOutsPerWorker[worker])-makeTimeStamp(logInsPerWorker[worker])
                numOfDaysPerWorkerArray[worker] = numOfDaysPerWorkerArray[worker] + 1
                logInsPerWorker[worker] = 0
            end
        end
end
--print the average hours for day per worker
for k,v in pairs(amountOfHoursPerWorkerArray) do
    print(k,tonumber(os.date('%H',v))/numOfDaysPerWorkerArray[k])
end
end
```

I think the problem is with the minus operation on time so I have these function:

```
function makeTimeStamp(dateString)
local pattern = "(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)"
local xhour, xminute, 
    xseconds = dateString:match(pattern)
local convertedTimestamp = os.time{ year=0,month=0,day=0,
    hour = xhour, minute = xminute, second = xseconds}
return convertedTimestamp
end
```

and becouse this is not working for me too- I have also this function which doing the difference:

```
function GetTimeDifference(intialTime,finalTime)
initialHour=tonumber(string.sub(intialTime,1,2)) *3600
initialMinute=tonumber(string.sub(intialTime,4,5))*60
initialSecond=tonumber(string.sub(intialTime,7,8))

finalHour=tonumber(string.sub(finalTime,1,2))*3600
finalMinute=tonumber(string.sub(finalTime,4,5))*60
finalSecond=tonumber(string.sub(finalTime,7,8))

totalInitialTime=initialHour+initialMinute+initialSecond
totalFinalTime=finalHour+finalMinute+finalSecond
local duration=totalFinalTime-totalInitialTime

formatedDuration="00:00:00"
if(duration<10) then
    formatedDuration="00:00:0"..duration
elseif(duration>9 and duration<60) then
    formatedDuration="00:00:"..duration
elseif(duration>59 and duration<=3600 ) then
    --minutes handler
    intermediateCalc=(duration/60)
    i,j=string.find(tostring(intermediateCalc),".")
    if(i==nil and j==nil) then
      formatedDuration="00:0"..intermediateCalc
    else
       min=string.sub(tostring(intermediateCalc),i,j)
       if(tonumber(min)<10) then
        formatedDuration="00:0"..min
       else
        formatedDuration="00:"..min
      end
    end

    newSeconds=duration%60
    if(newSeconds<10) then
        formatedDuration=formatedDuration..":0"
                ..newSeconds
    else
        formatedDuration=formatedDuration..":"
            ..newSeconds
    end
else
    --hour handler

    newMinutes=(finalMinute-initialMinute)/60
    if(newMinutes<0) then
      newMinutes=newMinutes*-1
    end

    if(newMinutes<10) then
        newMinutes="0"..newMinutes
    end

    newSeconds=(finalSecond-initialSecond)
    if(newSeconds<0) then
      newSeconds=newSeconds*-1
    end

    if(newSeconds<10) then
        newSeconds="0"..newSeconds
    end

    formatedDuration=(finalHour-initialHour)/3600
     ..":"..newMinutes..":"..newSeconds
end
return formatedDuration
end
```

still not working... please help!

Comment: what is "not working"? be more specific. I'm sure you can find one specific positionion in your code that is not doing what it is supposed to do. explain what it does for some example input and what it does instead.

Comment: `os.time{ year=0` the year is beyond allowed range, so `os.time` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are going for a 24h based clock value and that people check out the same day since you didn't specify anything about days being in the data. Assuming this, I'd use a string match pattern, which then modifies the values to a number to work with.
Using string.format to generate the same structure for the ouput could something like this:

```
function calculateWorktime(time_login, time_logout)
    login = {time_login:match("(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)")}
    logout = {time_logout:match("(%d+):(%d+):(%d+)")}

    in_h, out_h = tonumber(login[1]), tonumber(logout[1])
    in_m, out_m = tonumber(login[2]), tonumber(logout[2])
    in_s, out_s = tonumber(login[3]), tonumber(logout[3])

    if out_s < in_s then
        out_s = out_s + 60
        out_m = out_m - 1
    end

    if out_m < in_m then
        out_m = out_m + 60
        out_h = out_h - 1
    end

    worked_h = out_h - in_h
    worked_m = out_m - in_m
    worked_s = out_s - in_s

    worked_time = ("%02d:%02d:%02d"):format(worked_h, worked_m, worked_s)

    return worked_time
end
```

This generates "14:25:40" with login "08:10:32" and logout "22:36:12"